# ¿Por qué Java me verifica una firma digital ECDSA SHA-256 más rápido que C++?

Tags: java, c++, rendimiento

He escrito 2 programitas, uno en JAVA y otro en C++, que básicamente generan un par de claves privada y pública para a continuación firmar un mensaje con la privada y verificarlo despues con la pública.  En ambos casos estoy midiendo el tiempo que se tarda en hacer esto último de la verificación y sorprendentemente me sale que JAVA lo hace más rápido que C++ (2 milisegundos frente a 2.5 milisegundos) lo cual me parece desconcertante y es lo contrario de lo que esperaba obtener, estos tiempos son la media de haber hecho esta operación un gran número de veces dentro de un bucle for. Estos son los códigos:

JAVA:

```
public static double ecdsa() throws Exception {
/*
 * Generate an ECDSA signatures
 */

/*
 * Generate a key pair
 */
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");

ECGenParameterSpec kk = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");

keyGen.initialize(kk);

KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey priv = pair.getPrivate();
PublicKey pub = pair.getPublic();
/*
 * Create a Signature object and initialize it with the private key
 */

Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
dsa.initSign(priv);

String str = "This is string to sign";
byte[] strByte = str.getBytes("UTF-8");

dsa.update(strByte);

/*
 * Now that all the data to be signed has been read in, generate a
 * signature for it
 */
byte[] realSig = dsa.sign();
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

dsa.initVerify(pub);
dsa.update(strByte);
boolean res = dsa.verify(realSig);

long endTime = System.nanoTime();

double elapsedTime = (double) ((endTime - startTime) / Math.pow(10, 6));

return elapsedTime;
}
```

C++:

```
long double ecdsa_sample()
{
//Prepare ecdsa stuff

AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
ByteQueue privateKey, publicKey;

string message = "This is string to sign";

// Generate private key
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PrivateKey privKey;
privKey.Initialize( prng, ASN1::secp256r1() );
privKey.Save( privateKey );

// Create public key
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PublicKey pubKey;
privKey.MakePublicKey( pubKey );
pubKey.Save( publicKey );

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

// Load SHA256 key (in ByteQueue, PKCS#8 format)
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer signer( privateKey );

// Determine maximum size, allocate a string with that size
size_t siglen = signer.MaxSignatureLength();
string signature(siglen, 0x00);

// Sign, and trim signature to actual size
siglen = signer.SignMessage( prng, (const byte*)message.data(), message.size(), (byte*)signature.data() );
signature.resize(siglen);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

// Load public key (in ByteQueue, X509 format)
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier verifier( publicKey );

long double startecdsa_verification = getTime();

bool result = verifier.VerifyMessage( (const byte*)message.data(), message.size(), (const byte*)signature.data(), signature.size() );

//    if(result)
//        cout << "Verified signature on message" << endl;
//    else
//        cerr << "Failed to verify signature on message" << endl;

long double endecdsa_verification = getTime();

return (endecdsa_verification - startecdsa_verification);
}
```

Mi pregunta es por qué puede estar pasando esto? Quizás la instrucción que se usa en C++ está haciendo más operaciones que la de JAVA o algo por el estilo pero a mi parecer ambas están haciendo lo mismo. Necesito que ambos scripts hagan lo mismo para poder comparar performances en ambos lenguajes de la operación de verificación y a mi parecer C++ debería ser siempre más rápido que JAVA.
Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué optimizaciones has aplicado al compilar? Piensa que Java puede aplicar optimizaciones en tiempo de ejecución mientras que C++ sólo las aplica en tiempo de compilación. Por otro lado, la librería usada en Java podría ser (y será) muy diferente a la librería de C++, esto puede resultar también en diferencias de rendimiento.

Comment: Aparte de lo comentado por @PaperBirdMaster, a partir del estándar C++11 se implementaron ciertas características que permiten mejorar el rendimiento de las aplicaciones escritas en C++ (sintaxis `move` entre otras). El rendimiento con los últimos estándares tiende a ser superior

Answer (score 8):

Hace tiempo ya no es cierto que bajo condiciones reales Java sería mas lento que C++. Existen pruebas que indican que en varios casos de uso ( aun no en todos ) Java esta al mismo nivel de rendimiento o incluso mas alto que C++.

¿Sorprendente?

La explicación es en que Java produce un **bytecode** que está compilado en el momento que se arranca una aplicación en la máquina virtual en el mismo computador en que corre, y la máquina virtual optimiza constantemente el código, tomando en cuenta todas las particularidades del sistema como número de núcleos, tipo de procesador, etc.

La optimización de C++, al contrario, está más bajo control del desarrollador en la máquina en que trabaja, y no necesariamente ser optimizado durante el **runtime**.

Si haces una prueba midiendo el tiempo de ejecución de un método en Java, te vas a dar cuenta que la primera ejecución tarda mucho más que los siguientes, y que algunos métodos siguen ejecutarse más rápido desde un tiempo, gracias a la optimización en tiempo real que solamente el paradigma de un **JIT compiler** (just in time, compilador justo a tiempo) puede ofrecer.

Comment: "Justo a tiempo" sería una traducción aceptable.

Comment: *La optimización de C++, al contrario, está más bajo control del desarrollador en la máquina en que trabaja, y no necesariamente ser optimizado durante el **runtime**.* De hecho, la optimización de C++ **nunca** se va a dar en tiempo de ejecución.